Executable should automatically start with realtime priority on Windows
On an Windows 7 PC (used for legacy music software), I notice that enabling Windows Task Manager > Right click on process > Set priority > Realtime on a particular audio software improves massively the audio performance, and reduces the audio glitches.
(For context: I have already tried all other common techniques to modify latency and reduce glitches, and Realtime priority is really a game changer here).
How to configure a .exe to always automatically start with "Realtime priority"?

Create a batch file next to the executable, and put this inside it:
@start /realtime your-program.exe

And then always invoke the executable using that batch file.
For reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start#syntax
